# How to separate data bag item for different nodes?

Tags: chef-infra, databags

A basic data bag structure is: `/data_bags/[data bag name]/[data bag items]`

Let say I want to create a data bag for all the possible admins of all my nodes in a data bag called users.
i.e.

```
/data_bags/users/admin1.json
/data_bags/users/admin2.json
/data_bags/users/admin3.json
```

Now for `node1` I only want to have `admin1 and admin3` and for `node2` I want to have `admin2` and `admin3` as my admins.

How can I separate or structure my configuration in a way that I can specify or split my data bags item for each different node?

One idea I have is if we can do something like this.

```
/data_bags/node1/users/...
/data_bags/node2/users/...
```

I am a starter in chef, so if what I want to is stupid and should be handled other way then, I appreciate any information to point me to right direction.

Comment: What is the main goal after this ? Or to say it another way: how will you use those user informations ? this sounds like a XY problem of RBAC management more than a structure one. You can still have an attribute on each node telling which admins you wish for each node and fetch data_bag_item by this list.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to group by user or by host. We have the following data bag structure (more [docs](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/t3-base#users)):

```
{
    "id": "a-srv123-admin",
    ...
    "nodes": {
            "srv123.example.org": {
                    "sudo": "true"
            }
    }
}
```

More nodes can be added to the `node` hash. The corresponding [recipe](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/t3-base/blob/e99e05054a2e4bb95966345e437438f6306628a7/recipes/_users.rb#L42-L45) then searches for data bag items matching its own `node['fqdn']`:

```rb
users = search('users', "nodes:#{node['fqdn']}")
```

Of course, if it is more important to you to have it grouped by node, just do it the other way around and simply pick the data bag item matching the `fqdn` or similar attribute.

Comment: So the node needs to be separated inside the item itself? Looks disappointing. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It's just code and data. You can do, however you like. You can have data bag items per node, per user, or (per user per node, i.e.`srv123-johndoe.json` which contains just some `true` value). OTOH, you can put all that information into a single data bag item. I only illustrated the thing that works for us™ at a somewhat low complexity.

Comment: Hmm, But then I would probably have to use a file reader to search eligible data bag items. Having a solution to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568041/how-to-specify-a-data-bag-path-in-knife-rb-configuration-file) would be the best think I think, but sadly haven't found any.

Comment: I think you're thinking far too complex. Would it be okay for you to have items `users/srv123.example.org` containing the users?
Otherwise, I suggest that you edit your question a bit with maybe a desired structure. I'm not getting your point then.

Comment: I don't want to change the question too much, but I updated with one structure I had in mind.

Comment: Thx. I don't see a reason why you can't do a `knife data bag from file users data_bags/node1/users/johndoe.json` with this. Give it a try, please, I might be wrong. Be warned: It's IMHO against chef conventions, so others might get easily confused.

Comment: It responds with `Response: No data bag 'node1' could be found. Please create this data bag before adding items to it.`

Comment: This worked for me (after creating the data bag via `knife data bag create test`): `knife data bag from file test data_bags/foo/bar/test.json`. So it should work for your paths, too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I will just vote up for now, as I am not sure which solution works for me yet.

Answer (score 1):

The community [users cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/users) supports this feature. On each server you specify the user group you want managed and the cookbook will search the databag items for matching group memberships.

For an example, take a look at this answer:

- [Chef - how to use a list of attributes in a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008803/chef-how-to-use-a-list-of-attributes-in-a-script/39019127#39019127)

---

## Update

The "users" cookbook has an LWRP that defines which group of users should be installed on the server.

```
users_manage "admins1"
```

In the data bag you then specify the groups that the user is a member of. So for example "user1" would be included in servers who require the admins1 or admins2 group.

```
{
  "id": "user1",
  "ssh_keys": [
    "ssh-rsa I AM A DUMMY KEY 1"
  ],
  "groups": [
    "admins1",
    "admins2"
  ],
  "uid": 2001
}
```

You could of course create a group specific to each server, but that wouldn't scale terribly well. Personally I'd suggest group names based on user roles.

- admins
- devops
- developers
- deployers

Comment: I do use that  cookbook, I want to control which user is created on which node.

Comment: @Starx I've updated my answer. The link above has a working example (test kitchen project)

Comment: So, if a server has that group and only then the users will be created?

Comment: @Starx You run a recipe that creates the group, and then yes the users associated with that group are created. To fully understand what it's doing I suggesting reading the code for the "users_manage" LWRP. You'll discover a chef search of the "users" data bag: see: https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/users/blob/6a16e047b4a39b5d4c7a73a7e5e1c3313786bb86/providers/manage.rb#L39

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I will just vote up for now, as I am not sure which solution works for me yet.